# Reindexing an array after filtering in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I unset all the even index values from my array using this:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) if(!($key&1)) unset($arr [$key]);
```

and when I print the array structure using  `print_r()` I get:

```
Array ( [1] => name1 [3] => name2 )
```

How to reindexing after filtering my array so the structure would be:

```
Array ( [0] => name1 [1] => name2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Comment: please allow the roomba to purge this dupe page.